# Pandas: Drop consecutive duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

What's the most efficient way to drop only consecutive duplicates in pandas?

drop_duplicates gives this:

```
In [3]: a = pandas.Series([1,2,2,3,2], index=[1,2,3,4,5])

In [4]: a.drop_duplicates()
Out[4]: 
1    1
2    2
4    3
dtype: int64
```

But I want this:

```
In [4]: a.something()
Out[4]: 
1    1
2    2
4    3
5    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
a.loc[a.shift(-1) != a]

Out[3]:

1    1
3    2
4    3
5    2
dtype: int64
```

So the above uses boolean critieria, we compare the dataframe against the dataframe shifted by -1 rows to create the mask

Another method is to use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
In [82]:

a.loc[a.diff() != 0]
Out[82]:
1    1
2    2
4    3
5    2
dtype: int64
```

But this is slower than the original method if you have a large number of rows.

**Update**

Thanks to Bjarke Ebert for pointing out a subtle error, I should actually use `shift(1)` or just `shift()` as the default is a period of 1, this returns the first consecutive value:

```
In [87]:

a.loc[a.shift() != a]
Out[87]:
1    1
2    2
4    3
5    2
dtype: int64
```

Note the difference in index values, thanks @BjarkeEbert!

Comment: How should we do it, if we want to do a groupby at first then drop consecutive duplicates?
For example df.groupby(['Col1','Col2']) and save it again as dataframe?

Answer (score 37):

Here is an update that will make it work with multiple columns.  Use ".any(axis=1)" to combine the results from each column:

```
cols = ["col1","col2","col3"]
de_dup = a[cols].loc[(a[cols].shift() != a[cols]).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Can you do this but keep the last row?

Comment: It will only remove the last row if it is a duplicate.

Comment: @jonboy you need to use `shift(-1)` see the accepted answer

Comment: I don't think so - the "Update" on the accepted answer affirms that `shift()` is the proper expression.  In essence, if the current row is different than the next row (`shift()` or `shift(1)`), keep the current row.  See [pandas doc on shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

Answer (score 10):

Since we are going for `most efficient way`, i.e. performance, let's use array data to leverage NumPy. We will slice one-off slices and compare, similar to shifting method discussed earlier in `@EdChum's post`. But with NumPy slicing we would end up with one-less array, so we need to concatenate with a `True` element at the start to select the first element and hence we would have an implementation like so -

```
def drop_consecutive_duplicates(a):
    ar = a.values
    return a[np.concatenate(([True],ar[:-1]!= ar[1:]))]
```

Sample run -

```
In [149]: a
Out[149]: 
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    2
dtype: int64

In [150]: drop_consecutive_duplicates(a)
Out[150]: 
1    1
2    2
4    3
5    2
dtype: int64
```

Timings on large arrays comparing [`@EdChum's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19464054/) -

```
In [142]: a = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,5,(1000000)))

In [143]: %timeit a.loc[a.shift() != a]
100 loops, best of 3: 12.1 ms per loop

In [144]: %timeit drop_consecutive_duplicates(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 11 ms per loop

In [145]: a = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,5,(10000000)))

In [146]: %timeit a.loc[a.shift() != a]
10 loops, best of 3: 136 ms per loop

In [147]: %timeit drop_consecutive_duplicates(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 114 ms per loop
```

So, there's some improvement!

**Get major boost for values only!**

If only the values are needed, we could get major boost by simply indexing into the array data, like so -

```
def drop_consecutive_duplicates(a):
    ar = a.values
    return ar[np.concatenate(([True],ar[:-1]!= ar[1:]))]
```

Sample run -

```
In [170]: a = pandas.Series([1,2,2,3,2], index=[1,2,3,4,5])

In [171]: drop_consecutive_duplicates(a)
Out[171]: array([1, 2, 3, 2])
```

Timings -

```
In [173]: a = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,5,(10000000)))

In [174]: %timeit a.loc[a.shift() != a]
10 loops, best of 3: 137 ms per loop

In [175]: %timeit drop_consecutive_duplicates(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 61.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: I do not understand why timing for [147] and [175] differ? Can you explain what change have you made cuz I dont see any? Perhaps a typo?

Comment: @Biarys `[175]` is with the modified `Get major boost for values only!` section one, hence the time diff. The original one works on pandas-Series whereas the modified one on array as also listed in the post.

Comment: Oh I see. Hard to notice change from ```return a[...]``` vs ```return ar[....]```. Does your function work for dataframes?

Comment: @Biarys For dataframes, if you are looking for duplicate rows, we simply need to use `slicing` : `ar[:,:-1]!= ar[:,1:]`, alongwith `ALL` reduction.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that

Answer (score 6):

Here is a function that handles both `pd.Series` and `pd.Dataframes`. You can mask/drop, choose the axis and finally choose to drop with 'any' or 'all' 'NaN'. It is not optimized in term of computation time, but it has the advantage to be robust and pretty clear.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# To mask/drop successive values in pandas
def Mask_Or_Drop_Successive_Identical_Values(df, drop=False, 
                                             keep_first=True,
                                             axis=0, how='all'):

    '''
    #Function built with the help of:
    # 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428173/how-to-change-consecutive-repeating-values-in-pandas-dataframe-series-to-nan-or
    # 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463985/pandas-drop-consecutive-duplicates
    
    Input:
    df should be a pandas.DataFrame of a a pandas.Series
    Output:
    df of ts with masked or dropped values
    '''
    
    # Mask keeping the first occurrence
    if keep_first:
        df = df.mask(df.shift(1) == df)
    # Mask including the first occurrence
    else:
        df = df.mask((df.shift(1) == df) | (df.shift(-1) == df))

    # Drop the values (e.g. rows are deleted)    
    if drop:
        return df.dropna(axis=axis, how=how)        
    # Only mask the values (e.g. become 'NaN')
    else:
        return df
```

Here is a test code to include in the script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # With time series
    print("With time series:\n")
    ts = pd.Series([1,1,2,2,3,2,6,6,float('nan'), 6,6,float('nan'),float('nan')], 
                    index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
    
    print("#Original ts:")    
    print(ts)

    print("\n## 1) Mask keeping the first occurrence:")    
    print(Mask_Or_Drop_Successive_Identical_Values(ts, drop=False, 
                                                   keep_first=True))

    print("\n## 2) Mask including the first occurrence:")    
    print(Mask_Or_Drop_Successive_Identical_Values(ts, drop=False, 
                                                   keep_first=False))
    
    print("\n## 3) Drop keeping the first occurrence:")    
    print(Mask_Or_Drop_Successive_Identical_Values(ts, drop=True, 
                                                   keep_first=True))
    
    print("\n## 4) Drop including the first occurrence:")        
    print(Mask_Or_Drop_Successive_Identical_Values(ts, drop=True, 
                                                   keep_first=False))
    
    
    # With dataframes
    print("With dataframe:\n")
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15, 3))
    df.iloc[4:9,0]=40
    df.iloc[8:15,1]=22
    df.iloc[8:12,2]=0.23
        
    print("#Original df:")
    print(df)

    print("\n## 5) Mask keeping the first occurrence:") 
    print(Mask_Or_Drop_Successive_Identical_Values(df, drop=False, 
                                                   keep_first=True))

    print("\n## 6) Mask including the first occurrence:")    
    print(Mask_Or_Drop_Successive_Identical_Values(df, drop=False, 
                                                   keep_first=False))
    
    print("\n## 7) Drop 'any' keeping the first occurrence:")    
    print(Mask_Or_Drop_Successive_Identical_Values(df, drop=True, 
                                                   keep_first=True,
                                                   how='any'))
    
    print("\n## 8) Drop 'all' keeping the first occurrence:")    
    print(Mask_Or_Drop_Successive_Identical_Values(df, drop=True, 
                                                   keep_first=True,
                                                   how='all'))
    
    print("\n## 9) Drop 'any' including the first occurrence:")        
    print(Mask_Or_Drop_Successive_Identical_Values(df, drop=True, 
                                                   keep_first=False,
                                                   how='any'))

    print("\n## 10) Drop 'all' including the first occurrence:")        
    print(Mask_Or_Drop_Successive_Identical_Values(df, drop=True, 
                                                   keep_first=False,
                                                   how='all'))
```

And here is the expected result:

```
With time series:

#Original ts:
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     2.0
3     2.0
4     3.0
5     2.0
6     6.0
7     6.0
8     NaN
9     6.0
10    6.0
11    NaN
12    NaN
dtype: float64

## 1) Mask keeping the first occurrence:
0     1.0
1     NaN
2     2.0
3     NaN
4     3.0
5     2.0
6     6.0
7     NaN
8     NaN
9     6.0
10    NaN
11    NaN
12    NaN
dtype: float64

## 2) Mask including the first occurrence:
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     3.0
5     2.0
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     NaN
9     NaN
10    NaN
11    NaN
12    NaN
dtype: float64

## 3) Drop keeping the first occurrence:
0    1.0
2    2.0
4    3.0
5    2.0
6    6.0
9    6.0
dtype: float64

## 4) Drop including the first occurrence:
4    3.0
5    2.0
dtype: float64
With dataframe:

#Original df:
            0          1         2
0   -1.890137  -3.125224 -1.029065
1   -0.224712  -0.194742  1.891365
2    1.009388   0.589445  0.927405
3    0.212746  -0.392314 -0.781851
4   40.000000   1.889781 -1.394573
5   40.000000  -0.470958 -0.339213
6   40.000000   1.613524  0.271641
7   40.000000  -1.810958 -1.568372
8   40.000000  22.000000  0.230000
9   -0.296557  22.000000  0.230000
10  -0.921238  22.000000  0.230000
11  -0.170195  22.000000  0.230000
12   1.460457  22.000000 -0.295418
13   0.307825  22.000000 -0.759131
14   0.287392  22.000000  0.378315

## 5) Mask keeping the first occurrence:
            0          1         2
0   -1.890137  -3.125224 -1.029065
1   -0.224712  -0.194742  1.891365
2    1.009388   0.589445  0.927405
3    0.212746  -0.392314 -0.781851
4   40.000000   1.889781 -1.394573
5         NaN  -0.470958 -0.339213
6         NaN   1.613524  0.271641
7         NaN  -1.810958 -1.568372
8         NaN  22.000000  0.230000
9   -0.296557        NaN       NaN
10  -0.921238        NaN       NaN
11  -0.170195        NaN       NaN
12   1.460457        NaN -0.295418
13   0.307825        NaN -0.759131
14   0.287392        NaN  0.378315

## 6) Mask including the first occurrence:
           0         1         2
0  -1.890137 -3.125224 -1.029065
1  -0.224712 -0.194742  1.891365
2   1.009388  0.589445  0.927405
3   0.212746 -0.392314 -0.781851
4        NaN  1.889781 -1.394573
5        NaN -0.470958 -0.339213
6        NaN  1.613524  0.271641
7        NaN -1.810958 -1.568372
8        NaN       NaN       NaN
9  -0.296557       NaN       NaN
10 -0.921238       NaN       NaN
11 -0.170195       NaN       NaN
12  1.460457       NaN -0.295418
13  0.307825       NaN -0.759131
14  0.287392       NaN  0.378315

## 7) Drop 'any' keeping the first occurrence:
           0         1         2
0  -1.890137 -3.125224 -1.029065
1  -0.224712 -0.194742  1.891365
2   1.009388  0.589445  0.927405
3   0.212746 -0.392314 -0.781851
4  40.000000  1.889781 -1.394573

## 8) Drop 'all' keeping the first occurrence:
            0          1         2
0   -1.890137  -3.125224 -1.029065
1   -0.224712  -0.194742  1.891365
2    1.009388   0.589445  0.927405
3    0.212746  -0.392314 -0.781851
4   40.000000   1.889781 -1.394573
5         NaN  -0.470958 -0.339213
6         NaN   1.613524  0.271641
7         NaN  -1.810958 -1.568372
8         NaN  22.000000  0.230000
9   -0.296557        NaN       NaN
10  -0.921238        NaN       NaN
11  -0.170195        NaN       NaN
12   1.460457        NaN -0.295418
13   0.307825        NaN -0.759131
14   0.287392        NaN  0.378315

## 9) Drop 'any' including the first occurrence:
          0         1         2
0 -1.890137 -3.125224 -1.029065
1 -0.224712 -0.194742  1.891365
2  1.009388  0.589445  0.927405
3  0.212746 -0.392314 -0.781851

## 10) Drop 'all' including the first occurrence:
           0         1         2
0  -1.890137 -3.125224 -1.029065
1  -0.224712 -0.194742  1.891365
2   1.009388  0.589445  0.927405
3   0.212746 -0.392314 -0.781851
4        NaN  1.889781 -1.394573
5        NaN -0.470958 -0.339213
6        NaN  1.613524  0.271641
7        NaN -1.810958 -1.568372
9  -0.296557       NaN       NaN
10 -0.921238       NaN       NaN
11 -0.170195       NaN       NaN
12  1.460457       NaN -0.295418
13  0.307825       NaN -0.759131
14  0.287392       NaN  0.378315
```

Comment: You could also avoid explicitly checking the values `if keep_first:` is enough (and better style)

Answer (score 4):

For other Stack explorers, building off johnml1135's answer above.  This will remove the next duplicate from multiple columns but not drop all of the columns.  When the dataframe is sorted it will keep the first row but drop the second row if the "cols" match, even if there are more columns with non-matching information.

```
cols = ["col1","col2","col3"]
df = df.loc[(df[cols].shift() != df[cols]).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Just another way of doing it:**

```
a.loc[a.ne(a.shift())]
```

The method `pandas.Series.ne` is the *not equal* operator, so `a.ne(a.shift())` is equivalent to `a != a.shift()`. Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html).

Comment: This one is nice because people typically also want to drop if there are missing values but `NaN == NaN` evaluates to False. With `.ne(fill_value=12356789.345326)` you can still drop them. It just needs to be a float not in your data (easy if your data is ints or strings).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variant of [EdChum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19464054/857390) that treats consecutive NaNs as duplicates, too:

```py
def remove_consecutive_duplicates_and_nans(s):
    # By default, `shift` uses NaN as a fill value, which breaks our
    # removal of consecutive NaNs. Hence we use a different sentinel
    # object instead.
    shifted = s.astype(object).shift(-1, fill_value=object())
    return s.loc[
        (shifted != s)
        & ~(shifted.isna() & s.isna())
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new column.

```
df['match'] = df.col1.eq(df.col1.shift())
```

Then:

```
df = df[df['match']==False]
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach recommended by @johnml1135 does not work for me.

I figured out a similar approach though:

```
cols = ['Position', 'Offset']
df = df[df[cols] != df[cols].shift(-1)].dropna()
```

`shift(-1)` will keep the **last** duplicated row, and `shift(1)` will keep the **first** row.