# Pandas: using shift to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
id     event_path
111    google.com
111    yandex.ru
111     vk.com
222     twitter.com
222     twitter.com
333     twitter.com
333     facebook.com
```

Desire output

```
id     event_path
111    google.com
111    yandex.ru
111     vk.com
222     twitter.com
333     twitter.com
333     facebook.com
```

I try to use shift to column

```
df.loc[(df.event_path != df.event_path.shift()) & \
       (df.id == df.id.shift())]
```

and it returns me

```
id     event_path
111    google.com
111    yandex.ru
111     vk.com
222     twitter.com
333     facebook.com
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here, dropping duplicates or consecutive duplicates? If the latter then this is a dupe of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463985/pandas-drop-consecutive-duplicates

Comment: @EdChum I need to get data like 111 -> google.com, yandex.ru, vk.com; 222 -> twitter.com; 333 -> twitter.com -> facebook.com . I need union duplicate urls in the path of user

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you post a better explanation in your question as everyone is confused here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create helper Series for consecutives values with `shift`, add column `id` and get [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html). Last filter out by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1=df[~df[['id']].join(df['event_path'].ne(df['event_path'].shift()).cumsum()).duplicated()]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop_duplicates()

    id    event_path
0  111    google.com
1  111     yandex.ru
2  111        vk.com
3  222   twitter.com
5  333   twitter.com
6  333  facebook.com
```

---

IIUC:  OP wants to remove only when duplicate is adjacent.

```
df[df.eq(df.shift().bfill()).any(1)]

    id    event_path
0  111    google.com
1  111     yandex.ru
2  111        vk.com
4  222   twitter.com
5  333   twitter.com
6  333  facebook.com
```

Comment: thank you! But can you show me a decision with `shift()` ? Sometimes there are some columns, that I don't should drop duplicates

Comment: Construct example input and desired output that demonstrates what you're asking.

Comment: I've updated my post.  Beyond that, you'll have to put in some extra work explaining what you want.