# Drop consecutive duplicates in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Having a dataframe like:

```
## +---+---+
## | id|num|
## +---+---+
## |  2|3.0|
## |  3|6.0|
## |  3|2.0|
## |  3|1.0|
## |  2|9.0|
## |  4|7.0|
## +---+---+
```

and I want to remove the consecutive repetitions, and obtain:

```
## +---+---+
## | id|num|
## +---+---+
## |  2|3.0|
## |  3|6.0|
## |  2|9.0|
## |  4|7.0|
## +---+---+
```

I found [ways of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463985/pandas-drop-consecutive-duplicates) in Pandas but nothing in Pyspark.

Comment: By 'consecutive' I am guessing according to a certain order, such as by `num`. Is this correct, or do you also want this for a distribution of ids like `[1,2,1,1,2]` resulting in `[1,2,1,2]`?

Comment: The order should be given by ids, so your example is correct. [1, 2, 1, 1, 2] should result in [1, 2, 1, 2].

Comment: spark shuffles the record when it fetch from the data source so how you will ensure the order means which column to refer if i have to give a row number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer should work as you desired, however there might be room for some optimization:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
test_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (2,3.0),(3,6.0),(3,2.0),(3,1.0),(2,9.0),(4,7.0)
    ], ("id", "num"))
test_df = test_df.withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())  # create temporary ID because window needs an ordered structure
w = W.orderBy("idx")
get_last= when(lag("id", 1).over(w) == col("id"), False).otherwise(True) # check if the previous row contains the same id

test_df.withColumn("changed",get_last).filter(col("changed")).select("id","num").show() # only select the rows with a changed ID
```

Output:

```py
+---+---+
| id|num|
+---+---+
|  2|3.0|
|  3|6.0|
|  2|9.0|
|  4|7.0|
+---+---+
```