# Drop consecutive duplicates in a Spark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, time-series, partitioning, apache-spark-sql

The situation is the following: I have a time-series Dataframe consisting of one index column which orders the sequence; and a column of some discrete value like this:

```
id    value
0     A
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     A
5     A
6     A
7     B
```

I now want to reduce all **consecutive duplicates**, so that it looks like this:

```
id    value
0     A
2     B
3     C
4     A
7     B
```

I've come up with a window and using `lag()`, `when()` and filtering afterwards. The problem is that window requires a specific partition column. What I want however is to just drop the consecutive rows in each partition first and after that check for the partition borders (since the window works per partition, so consecutive rows over partition borders still exist).

```
df_with_block = df.withColumn(
            "block", (col("id") / df.rdd.getNumPartitions()).cast("int"))

window = Window.partitionBy("block").orderBy("id")

get_last = when(lag("value", 1).over(window) == col("value"), False).otherwise(True)

reduced_df = unificated_with_block.withColumn("reduced",get_last)
                .where(col("reduced")).drop("reduced")
```

In the first line, I created a new dataframe with uniformly distributed partitions by integer dividing the id's. get_last then contains boolean values depending on the current rows being equal to the preceding. reduced_df then filters the duplicates out.

The problem are now the partition borders:

```
id    value
0     A
2     B
3     C
4     A
6     A
7     B
```

As you can see, row with id=6 didn't get removed since it was processed in a different partition. I'm thinking about different ideas to solve this:

- Use `coalesce()` to combine partitions and filter again?
- Find some way to access first value from the next partition
- Use an RDD instead of a Dataframe to do all of this
- Change my partitioning function so that it doesn't cut in places where duplicates are located (How?)

I'm curious how that could work out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop consecutive duplicates in a pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146821/drop-consecutive-duplicates-in-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: It is to an extent, but I wanted it performed in parallel, so without Spark having to move all data to a single partition.

Answer (score 4):

##### Without partitioning:

You can use window without partition, using the same logic you already used.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F  
  
data = [(0,"A"), (1,"A"),(2,"B"),(3,"C"),(4,"A"),(5,"A"),(6,"A"),(7,"B")]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ["id","value"])

w = Window().orderBy(F.col("id"))
df = df.withColumn("dupe", F.col("value") == F.lag("value").over(w))\
.filter((F.col("dupe") == False) | (F.col("dupe").isNull())).drop("dupe")

df.show()
```

Resulting in:

```
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  0|    A|
|  2|    B|
|  3|    C|
|  4|    A|
|  7|    B|
+---+-----+
```

##### With partitioning:

Another solution with partitioning would be to partition it by value resulting in:
Assuming that the id of a duplicate record is only increased by 1.

```
w = Window().partitionBy("value").orderBy(F.col("id"))
df = df.withColumn("dupe", F.col("id") - F.lag("id").over(w))\
.filter((F.col("dupe") > 1) | (F.col("dupe").isNull())).drop("dupe")\
.orderBy("id")
```

Comment: Do you have a way of achieving the same thing in the context of structured streaming?