# Multiple values in a row, keep only the first

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Series with integers. It looks something like this.

```py
A = pd.Series({'data':[1,1,3,3,4,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,4,4]})
```

My desired output is

```py
[1,3,4,3,6,4]
```

In other words, keep the first value, ignore any multiples. When `3` is reached, keep it, ignoring the multiple values, then `4` then `3` and so on.

The `unique()` function is similar to what I want, but not quite the same. I need to preserve the order, and, if a number appears again at a later point, keep it as well.

This wouldn't be hard to do by simply looping through, but I would MUCH prefer a vectorized solution.

Comment: I _think_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463985/pandas-drop-consecutive-duplicates covers this.

Comment: A = A.loc[A.shift() != data]