# How to find the first consecutive value in a Pandas dataframe column and delete that row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns and rows. I wish to find the consecutive duplicate values in a particular column and delete the entire row of the first occurrence of that duplicate value.

I found a possible solution but it works only with pandas series.
`a.loc[a.shift() != a]`
[This is the link to the mentioned solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463985/pandas-drop-consecutive-duplicates)

To visualize my dataframe would be something like this:

```
Index column0 column1 column2 column3
row0 0.5 25 26 27
row1 0.5 30 31 32
row2 1.0 35 36 37
row3 1.5 40 41 42
```

```
Index column0 column1 column2 column3
row1 0.5 30 31 32
row2 1.0 35 36 37
row3 1.5 40 41 42
```

This would be expected result with the **row0** deleted.

P.S This duplicate occurrence does not happen at the beginning in my data, it occurs in random in the **column0**.

Comment: `df.loc[df.column0.shift(-1) != df.column0]`?

Comment: @QuangHoang That worked! Thank you! I'm such a noob. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:, 0].shift(-1) != df.iloc[:, 0]]
```

This is the answer! Thank you [Quang Hoang!](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang)

Answer (score 0):

A step by step solution is here.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,7,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))    

number_of_occurrence_on_first_column = df.groupby('A')['A'].count()    

has_duplicates_items = number_of_occurrence_on_first_column[number_of_occurrence_on_first_column >1].index    

all_duplicate_items = df[df.A.isin(has_duplicates_items)]    

need_to_delete = pd.DataFrame(all_duplicate_items['A']).drop_duplicates().index
df = df.drop(need_to_delete)
```