# Drop consecutive duplicates across multiple columns - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

There's a few questions on this but not using location based indexing of multiple columns: [Pandas: Drop consecutive duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463985/pandas-drop-consecutive-duplicates).

I have a `df` that may contain consecutive duplicate values across specific rows. I want to remove them for the last two columns only. Using the `df` below, I want to drop rows where values in `year` and `sale` are the same.

I'm getting an error using the query below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10, 12, 12],
               'year': ['12', '14', '14', '13', '15', '15'],
              'sale': ['55', '40', '40', '84', '31', '32']})

cols = df.iloc[:,1:3]

# Option 1
df = df.loc[df[cols] != df['cols'].shift()].reset_index(drop = True)
```

> ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only

```
# Option 2
df = df[df.iloc[:,1:3].diff().ne(0).any(1)].reset_index(drop = True)
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Intended Output:

```
   month  year  sale
0      1  2012    55
1      4  2014    40
3     10  2013    84
4     12  2014    31
5     12  2014    32
```

Notes:

1) I need to use index label for selecting columns as the labels will change. I need something fluid.

2) `drop_duplicates` isn't appropriate here as I only want to drop rows that are the same as the previous row. I don't want to drop the same value altogether.

Comment: does this suffice? df.groupby(['year','sale'],as_index=False).first()

Comment: So, can't be hard-coded labels.Will update question. Performance may be a worry with groupby too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I want to drop rows where values in `year` and `sale` are the same* That means you can calculate the difference, check if they are equal zero on `year` and `sale`:

```
# if the data are numeric
# s = df[['year','sale']].diff().ne(0).any(1)

s = df[['year','sale']].ne(df[['year','sale']].shift()).any(1)
df[s]
```

Output:

```
   month  year  sale
0      1  2012    55
1      4  2014    40
3     10  2013    84
4     12  2014    31
5     12  2014    32
```

Comment: Sorry they are strings @Quang Hoang

Comment: @jonboy see update with `shift`. But why would you want/let `year` and `sale` as text. They are, intuitively, numerical valued.

Comment: Yeh, it doesn't represent my actual data. It's a dummy set. If you change it to indexed based it's great. `df = df[df.iloc[:,1:3].ne(df.iloc[:,1:3].shift()).any(1)].reset_index(drop = True)`

Comment: You can also use `cols = df.iloc[:,1:3]; df[cols.ne(cols.shift()).any(1)]`.