# Pandas drop duplicated values partially

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3],
                 'B':[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                 'C':[7, 2, 2, 5, 7, 2, 2]})
```

I would like to drop the duplicated values from columns A and C. However, I want it to work partially.

If I use

`df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','C'], keep='first')`

It will drop row 2, 5, 6. However, I only want to drop row 2 and 6. The desired results are like:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 3, 4, 5, 3],
                 'B':[0, 2, 4, 5, 6],
                 'C':[7, 2, 5, 7, 2]})
```

Comment: What do you mean by *discretely*?

Comment: @yatu I mean partially drop the duplicated values.

Comment: @yatu Since df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','C'], keep='first') will drop the ALL the duplicated rows (2, 5, 6) and keep the first (1), BUt I ONLY want to drop row 2 and 6, that's what I mean by partially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do this, using [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
df.loc[(df[["A", "C"]].shift() != df[["A", "C"]]).any(axis=1)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  0  7
1  3  2  2
2  4  4  5
3  5  5  7
4  3  6  2
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463985/pandas-drop-consecutive-duplicates) is a nice reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep every second repetition of `A`, `C` pair:

```py
df=df.loc[df.groupby(["A", "C"]).cumcount()%2==0]
```

Outputs:

```py
   A  B  C
0  1  0  7
1  3  2  2
3  4  4  5
4  5  5  7
5  3  6  2
```