# Drop consecutive duplicates in Pandas dataframe if repeated more than n times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

Building off the question/solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463985/pandas-drop-consecutive-duplicates), I'm trying to set a parameter that will only remove consecutive duplicates if the same value occurs 5 (or more) times consecutively...

I'm able to apply the solution in the linked post which uses `.shift()` to check if the previous (or a specified value in the past or future by adjusting the shift periods parameter) equals the current value, but how could I adjust this to check several consecutive values simultaneously?

Suppose a dataframe that looks like this:

```
x    y

1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    4
9    4
10   4
11   4
12   2
```

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
x    y

1    2
2    2
3    3
8    4
9    4
10   4
11   4
12   2
```

Where we lose rows 4,5,6,7 because we found five consecutive 3's in the y column. But keep rows 1,2 because it we only find two consecutive 2's in the y column. Similarly, keep rows 8,9,10,11 because we only find four consecutive 4's in the y column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `cumsum` on the differences to find the consecutive blocks. Then `groupby().transform('size')` to get the size of the blocks:

```
thresh = 5
s = df['y'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()

small_size = s.groupby(s).transform('size') < thresh
first_rows = ~s.duplicated()

df[small_size | first_rows]
```

Output:

```
     x  y
0    1  2
1    2  2
2    3  3
7    8  4
8    9  4
9   10  4
10  11  4
11  12  2
```

Comment: Very close @Quang Hoang! But I'd like to keep the row at index 2 of the original df - keep the first instance and remove the following consecutive duplicates if we find that five or more consecutive duplicates appear. Thank you!

Comment: @azam I see, updated the answer to keep the first rows.

Comment: Worked for test dataset and when applied to full dataset!

Comment: to add to this, wondering your thoughts: instead of dropping the consecutive duplicates, do you have any thoughts on setting them to NaN to keep the original shape of the df?

Comment: `df.loc[~(small_size | first_rows)] = np.nan`.

Answer (score 0):

Not straight forward, I would go with @Quang Hoang

Create a column which gives the number of times a values is duplicated. In this case I used `np.where()` and `df.duplicated()` and assigned any `count> 4` to be `NaN`

```
df['g']=np.where(df.groupby('y').transform(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep='last').count())>4, np.nan,1)
```

I then create two dataframes. One where I drop all the `NaNs` and one with only `NaNs`. In the one with `NaNs`, I drop all apart from the last index using `.last_valid_index()`. I then append them and sort by index using `.sort_index()`. I use `iloc[:,:2])` to slice out new column I created above

```
df.dropna().append(df.loc[df[df.g.isna()].last_valid_index()]).sort_index().iloc[:,:2]

     x    y
0    1.0  2.0
1    2.0  2.0
6    7.0  3.0
7    8.0  4.0
8    9.0  4.0
9   10.0  4.0
10  11.0  4.0
11  12.0  2.0
```