# Keep first occurrence of value pattern in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

time = ["2020-11-24 08:34:25.963422", "2020-11-24 08:34:25.963469", "2020-11-24 08:34:25.963681", "2020-11-24 08:34:27.051432", \
        "2020-11-24 08:34:27.051855", "2020-11-24 08:34:52.793429", "2020-11-24 08:34:52.793465", "2020-11-24 08:34:52.793641", \
        "2020-11-24 08:34:53.880143", "2020-11-24 08:34:53.880541", "2020-11-24 08:35:04.853417", "2020-11-24 08:35:04.853450", \
        "2020-11-24 08:35:04.853605"]

name = ["request", "request", "request", "complete", "complete", "request", "request", "request", "complete", "complete", "request", "request", "request"]

data = {"time": time, "name": name}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


    time                        name
0   2020-11-24 08:34:25.963422  request
1   2020-11-24 08:34:25.963469  request
2   2020-11-24 08:34:25.963681  request
3   2020-11-24 08:34:27.051432  complete
4   2020-11-24 08:34:27.051855  complete
5   2020-11-24 08:34:52.793429  request
6   2020-11-24 08:34:52.793465  request
7   2020-11-24 08:34:52.793641  request
8   2020-11-24 08:34:53.880143  complete
9   2020-11-24 08:34:53.880541  complete
10  2020-11-24 08:35:04.853417  request
11  2020-11-24 08:35:04.853450  request
12  2020-11-24 08:35:04.853605  request
```

I want to keep first occurrence of the pattern `request` and `complete` so the output would look like this:

```
    time                        name
0   2020-11-24 08:34:25.963422  request
1   2020-11-24 08:34:27.051432  complete
2   2020-11-24 08:34:52.793429  request
3   2020-11-24 08:34:53.880143  complete
4   2020-11-24 08:35:04.853417  request
```

I already tried to use `iloc` and slicing the dataframe but not succeeded to get anything useful. I could start looping and counting the occurrences row by row but I think there must be a more efficient method.

Comment: Take a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463985/pandas-drop-consecutive-duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to search just for the rows where `name` doesn't equal the next row's `name`, and use `loc` to filter out the duplicate rows:

```
df.loc[df.name.ne(df.name.shift())]

                          time      name
0   2020-11-24 08:34:25.963422   request
3   2020-11-24 08:34:27.051432  complete
5   2020-11-24 08:34:52.793429   request
8   2020-11-24 08:34:53.880143  complete
10  2020-11-24 08:35:04.853417   request
```