# How to apply a command to multiple column elements?

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda, apply

I have the table below and would like to apply onde command  to compare and eliminate duplicate values ​​in row `n` and `n + 1` in multiple dataframes `(df1, df2)`.

**Comand sugestion:**  `.diff().ne(0)`

How to apply this command only to the elements of columns A ,C and D, using the commands `def` ,`lambda` or `apply`?

`df1:`

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| **22** | 33 |
| **22** | 4 |
| 3 | 55 |
| 1 | 55 |

`df2:`

| C | D |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2.3 |
| 45 | **33** |
| **7** | **33** |
| **7** | 11 |

The expected output is:
`df1:`

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | 33 |
| **NaN** | 4 |
| 3 | 55 |
| 1 | 55 |

`df2:`

| C | D |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2.3 |
| 45 | **33** |
| **7** | **NaN** |
| **NaN** | 11 |

The other desired option would be to delete the duplicated lines, keeping the first number.

`df1:`

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| **22** | 33 |
| **row deleted** | **row deleted** |
| 3 | **55** |
| **row deleted** | **row deleted** |

`df2:`

| C | D |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2.3 |
| 45 | **33** |
| **row deleted** | **row deleted** |
| **row deleted** | **row deleted** |

Comment: What is the expect output?

Comment: what's your desired output and whay have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463985/pandas-drop-consecutive-duplicates) answer, you can create a mask for a single column in your dataframe (here for example for column `A`) with

```
mask1 = df['A'].shift() == df['A']
```

Since this shows `True` if there was a duplicate, you need to slice the DataFrame with the negation of the mask

```
df = df[~mask1]
```

To do this for multiple columns, make a mask for each column and use NumPy's `logical_or` to combine the masks. Then slice `df` with the final mask.

Answer (score 1):

With your suggested command: `.diff().ne(0)` (or `.diff.eq(0)`)

**Option 1**: set `NaN` to duplicate values

```
# For 1 column
df1.loc[df1['A'].diff().eq(0), 'A'] = np.NaN
print(df1)

      A   B
0  22.0  33
1   NaN   4
2   3.0  55
3   1.0  55

# For multiple columns
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: x[x.diff().ne(0)])
print(df2)

      C     D
0   5.0   2.3
1  45.0  33.0
2   7.0   NaN
3   NaN  11.0
```

**Option 2**: delete rows

```
>>> df1[df1.diff().ne(0).all(axis=1)]
    A   B
0  22  33
2   3  55

>>> df2[df2.diff().ne(0).all(axis=1)]
    C     D
0   5   2.3
1  45  33.0
```