# Pandas DataFrame drop consecutive duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to modify drop_duplicates in a such way:
For example, I've got DataFrame with rows:

```
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | el1            | 
| Second   | el2            |
| Second   | el8            |
| First    | el3            |
| Second   | el4            |
| Second   | el5            |
| First    | el6            |
| Second   | el9            |
```

And I need not to drop all duplicates, but only consecutive ones. So as a result a want:

```
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | el1            | 
| Second   | el2            |
| First    | el3            |
| Second   | el4            |
| First    | el6            |
| Second   | el9            |
```

Tried to do it with for, but maybe there are better ways

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Drop consecutive duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463985/pandas-drop-consecutive-duplicates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it by using `shift()` as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A header': ['First', 'Second', 'Second', 'First', 'Second', 'Second', 'First', 'Second'],
    'Another header': ['el1', 'el2', 'el8', 'el3', 'el4', 'el5', 'el6', 'el9'],
})

print(df)
"""
  A header Another header
0    First            el1
1   Second            el2
2   Second            el8
3    First            el3
4   Second            el4
5   Second            el5
6    First            el6
7   Second            el9
"""

df2 = df[df['A header'] != df['A header'].shift(1)]

print(df2)
"""
  A header Another header
0    First            el1
1   Second            el2
3    First            el3
4   Second            el4
6    First            el6
7   Second            el9
"""
```

Using `shift(1)`, you can compare each row with the row's previous row.

For more information, see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Comment: What should I do if I want to check by multiple columns? Because if I am doing      df[df[['A header', 'C header']] != df[['A header', 'C header']].shift(1)] , I get Nones

Comment: @hurricane133 Then, you can do like this: `df2 = df[(df['A header'] != df['A header'].shift(1)) & (df['C header'] != df['C header'].shift(1))]`

Answer (score 1):

extract dup:

```
l=[]
for i in range(len(df1)-1):
    if df1['A header'][i]==df1['A header'][i+1] :
        l.append(i+1)
```

drop dup:

```
 df1.drop(l, inplace=True)
```

Comment: replace df1 by your dataframe name