# Slicing dataframe with repetitive sequence

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, slice

I need your help slicing a dataframe with a lot of repetitive sequences. For instance:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3...]
```

I tried the `drop_duplicates(subset= "", keep="last")` options but I got something like `a = [1, 2, 3]` so only one sequence of numbers is left. For each sequence from 1 to 3, I need to get the last number.

I need the final result to be like: `a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3...]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Drop consecutive duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463985/pandas-drop-consecutive-duplicates)

Comment: I am working with a multiple columns data frame