# Drop consecutive duplicates for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have some time-series data with multiple columns:

```
         date hardware location  group   rtype  value
0 2021-03-01     desk       NY  opera  type-s      0
1 2021-03-01     desk       NJ  opera  type-s    200
2 2021-03-01     desk       IL  opera  type-s    100
3 2022-08-01     desk       NY  opera  type-s    275
4 2021-08-25     desk       IL  opera  type-s    100
5 2022-09-16     desk       IL  opera  type-s     30
6 2022-09-16     desk       NY  opera  type-s      0
7 2022-11-01     desk       NJ  opera  type-s      0
8 2022-11-01     desk       IL  opera  type-s      0
```

I want to remove consecutive duplicates ignoring the date, e.g.

```
...
2 2021-03-01     desk       IL  opera  type-s    100
3 2022-08-01     desk       NY  opera  type-s    275
4 2021-08-25     desk       IL  opera  type-s    100
...
```

Rows with index 2, 4 are duplicates, and I want to only keep the first one.

I tried two approaches,

1. using `drop_duplicates` which also drops non-consecutive duplicates,
   and
2. using `shift() !=`  that I found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55360617/1872234) which also seems to be doing the same thing.

Here is my test code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
date,hardware,location,group,rtype,value
2021-03-01,desk,NY,opera,type-s,0
2021-03-01,desk,NJ,opera,type-s,200
2021-03-01,desk,IL,opera,type-s,100
2022-08-01,desk,NY,opera,type-s,275
2021-08-25,desk,IL,opera,type-s,100
2022-09-16,desk,IL,opera,type-s,30
2022-09-16,desk,NY,opera,type-s,0
2022-11-01,desk,NJ,opera,type-s,0
2022-11-01,desk,IL,opera,type-s,0
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates=['date'])

print('\nOriginal \n', df.to_string())

columns = ['hardware', 'location', 'group', 'rtype']


dedup_cols = columns + ['value']

df = df.drop_duplicates(
    subset=dedup_cols, keep='first').reset_index(drop=True)

de_dup = df.loc[(df[dedup_cols].shift() != df[dedup_cols]).any(axis=1)]

print('\nDrop_duplicates: \n', df.to_string())
print('\nShift_filter: \n', de_dup.to_string())

expected = """
date,hardware,location,group,rtype,value
2021-03-01,desk,NY,opera,type-s,0
2021-03-01,desk,NJ,opera,type-s,200
2021-03-01,desk,IL,opera,type-s,100
2022-08-01,desk,NY,opera,type-s,275
2022-09-16,desk,IL,opera,type-s,30
2022-09-16,desk,NY,opera,type-s,0
2022-11-01,desk,NJ,opera,type-s,0
2022-11-01,desk,IL,opera,type-s,0
"""

expected_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(expected), parse_dates=['date'])

print('Equal drop_duplicates ? ', expected_df.equals(df))
print('Equal shift_filter ? ', expected_df.equals(de_dup))
print('Same result from the two techniques? ', de_dup.equals(df))
print('\nExpected:\n', expected_df.to_string())
```

OUTPUT:

```
Original 
         date hardware location  group   rtype  value
0 2021-03-01     desk       NY  opera  type-s      0
1 2021-03-01     desk       NJ  opera  type-s    200
2 2021-03-01     desk       IL  opera  type-s    100
3 2022-08-01     desk       NY  opera  type-s    275
4 2021-08-25     desk       IL  opera  type-s    100
5 2022-09-16     desk       IL  opera  type-s     30
6 2022-09-16     desk       NY  opera  type-s      0
7 2022-11-01     desk       NJ  opera  type-s      0
8 2022-11-01     desk       IL  opera  type-s      0

Drop_duplicates: 
         date hardware location  group   rtype  value
0 2021-03-01     desk       NY  opera  type-s      0
1 2021-03-01     desk       NJ  opera  type-s    200
2 2021-03-01     desk       IL  opera  type-s    100
3 2022-08-01     desk       NY  opera  type-s    275
4 2022-09-16     desk       IL  opera  type-s     30
5 2022-11-01     desk       NJ  opera  type-s      0
6 2022-11-01     desk       IL  opera  type-s      0

Shift_filter: 
         date hardware location  group   rtype  value
0 2021-03-01     desk       NY  opera  type-s      0
1 2021-03-01     desk       NJ  opera  type-s    200
2 2021-03-01     desk       IL  opera  type-s    100
3 2022-08-01     desk       NY  opera  type-s    275
4 2022-09-16     desk       IL  opera  type-s     30
5 2022-11-01     desk       NJ  opera  type-s      0
6 2022-11-01     desk       IL  opera  type-s      0
Equal drop_duplicates ?  False
Equal shift_filter ?  False
Same result from the two techniques?  True

Expected:
         date hardware location  group   rtype  value
0 2021-03-01     desk       NY  opera  type-s      0
1 2021-03-01     desk       NJ  opera  type-s    200
2 2021-03-01     desk       IL  opera  type-s    100
3 2022-08-01     desk       NY  opera  type-s    275
4 2022-09-16     desk       IL  opera  type-s     30
5 2022-09-16     desk       NY  opera  type-s      0
6 2022-11-01     desk       NJ  opera  type-s      0
7 2022-11-01     desk       IL  opera  type-s      0
```

I recon the `drop_duplicates` method is not suitable.

I was hoping the second method would work but I don't completely understand why it doesn't.

I am thinking some approach with `group_by` + `shift` and take a consecutive diff and then drop where diff is 0. Any ideas?

Comment: rows 2 and 4 are not consecutive, how do you define "consecutive"?

Comment: I mean "adjacent" dates within a group of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you want to consider consecutive values **per group**.

Then use [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
cols = ['hardware', 'location', 'group', 'rtype']
out = df.loc[df['value'].ne(df.groupby(cols)['value'].shift())]
```

Output:

```
        date hardware location  group   rtype  value
0 2021-03-01     desk       NY  opera  type-s      0
1 2021-03-01     desk       NJ  opera  type-s    200
2 2021-03-01     desk       IL  opera  type-s    100
3 2022-08-01     desk       NY  opera  type-s    275
5 2022-09-16     desk       IL  opera  type-s     30
6 2022-09-16     desk       NY  opera  type-s      0
7 2022-11-01     desk       NJ  opera  type-s      0
8 2022-11-01     desk       IL  opera  type-s      0
```

Comment: When I execute this code, it seems to be producing the same result as the other two.

Comment: You can't post formatted code as comment. But please check carefully, the output I provided is matching your expected output (only row 4 is dropped).

Comment: Oh yes you are right, I was using the incorrect dataframe ::facepalm::

Comment: My original code has a bug, which is also why the two approaches give the same output...

Comment: No worries. NB. If the dates must be increasing ensure the dates are sorted prior to running the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
date,hardware,location,group,rtype,value
2021-03-01,desk,NY,opera,type-s,0
2022-09-16,desk,NY,opera,type-s,0
2021-03-01,desk,NJ,opera,type-s,200
2021-03-01,desk,IL,opera,type-s,100
2022-08-01,desk,NY,opera,type-s,275
2021-08-25,desk,IL,opera,type-s,100
2022-09-16,desk,IL,opera,type-s,30
2022-09-16,desk,NY,opera,type-s,0
2022-11-01,desk,NJ,opera,type-s,0
2022-11-01,desk,IL,opera,type-s,0
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates=['date'])
dup_cols = ['hardware', 'location', 'group', 'rtype', 'value']

mask =(df[dup_cols] == df[dup_cols].shift(1)).all(axis=1).fillna(False)


df = df[~mask].reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Try this one. I hope it will work